# Avoid refresh the whole page after submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

in the code below there is a form with the name of FormData where every time I submit the data, it updates the entire page. I wish this did not happen when submit the data, it would execute the action q without refreshing the whole page. This behavior is normal or I'm doing something wrong?

My code:

```
    <ui:decorate template="/resources/Template.xhtml">
    <ui:define id="content" name="content">
        <p:growl id="war"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ok{  
                color: #336600
            }
            .erro{
                color: #D20005;
            }
        </style>
        <div style="width: 90%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; ">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Lista de Arquivos Armazenados                        
                </f:facet>       
                <h:form id="pesquisar">
                    <p:toolbar style="width: 100%;">
                        <p:toolbarGroup align="left" >
                            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="0">                            
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:toolbarGroup>                        
                        <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="5" cellpadding="0">
                                <h:outputLabel value="De: "/>  
                                <p:inputMask mask="99/99/9999" value="#{arquivoBean.dataInicial}" size="10"/>
                                <h:outputLabel value="Até: "/>  
                                <p:inputMask mask="99/99/9999" value="#{arquivoBean.datafinal}" size="10"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="Buscar" action="#{arquivoBean.listar()}"  ajax="false"/>
                                <br/>
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check" value="#{arquivoBean.pendente}"
                                                         itemLabel="Pendente">
                                    <p:ajax process="@this" event="change" listener="#{arquivoBean.listarPendente()}" />
                                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </h:panelGrid>

                        </p:toolbarGroup>
                    </p:toolbar>
                </h:form>
            </p:panel>
            <br/>
            <p:dataTable id="dataTable"
                         var="Arquivo"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorPosition="bottom"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="100"
                         rows="100"
                         sortBy="#{Arquivo.id}"
                         value="#{arquivoBean.dataModelArquivo}"  
                         rowStyleClass="#{Arquivo.pendente eq 1 ? 'ok' : 'erro'}"
                         emptyMessage="Você ainda não ativou uma empresa ou não existe postagem para esta Empresa">
                <p:column headerText="ID">
                    #{Arquivo.id}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Nome">
                    #{Arquivo.nomeMury}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Envio">
                    #{Arquivo.dataEnvio}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Produto" width="10px;">
                    <h:form id="formProduto">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-zoomout" value="" 
                                         action="#{arquivoBean.listarProdutoPorArquivo()}" 
                                         oncomplete="prodDialog.show()"
                                         onclick="listarProd([{name: 'ArquivoId', value:#{Arquivo.id}}]);">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{Arquivo}" target="#{arquivoBean.arquivo}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:remoteCommand name="listarProd" action="#{arquivoBean.listarProdutoPorArquivo()}" update=":formDataTable:dataTableProd">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{Arquivo}" target="#{arquivoBean.arquivo}"/>
                        </p:remoteCommand>
                    </h:form>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Data" width="10px;">
                    <h:form id="formData">

                        <p:inputMask id="entrada#{cc.clientId}" mask="99/99/9999" value="#{Arquivo.dataEntrada}"
                                     onkeypress="if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                                                     test([{name: 'rowIndex', value:#{Arquivo.id}}]);
                                                     return;
                                                 }"
                                     size="8">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" type="date" timeZone="GMT-03:00"/>
                        </p:inputMask>
                        <p:remoteCommand name="test" action="#{arquivoBean.inserirDataNota()}">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{Arquivo}" target="#{arquivoBean.arquivo}"/>
                        </p:remoteCommand>
                    </h:form>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <h:form id="formDataTable">
                <p:dialog closeOnEscape="true" 
                          widgetVar="prodDialog" 
                          modal="true" 
                          header="Lista de Produtos da NF-e"
                          style="width: 300; height: 500"
                          position="center">
                    <p:dataTable
                        id="dataTableProd"
                        var="XmlItens"
                        paginator="true"
                        paginatorPosition="bottom"
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="10"
                        rows="10"
                        value="#{arquivoBean.listaProd}">
                        <p:column headerText="ID">
                            #{XmlItens.id}
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Nome">
                            #{XmlItens.descricaoProd}
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Envio">
                            #{XmlItens.chaveNfe}
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:decorate>
```

Comment: Which component submits the `<h:form id="formData"/>`?

Comment: Please conform to SSCCE.org  and post only relevant part of your code.

Comment: i post. about the componets, just a inputMask... Nay one knows why page refresh in submit?

Answer (score 0):

First: The method on your managedBean must be **void** or return a String null 
Second: you must write which ones components do you want to update after de action works.

Like primefaces example:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml